# clean up draft items in workbox

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, workbox

I have a requirement where I have to clean up the draft items in sitecore workbox which are there for more than two years in workbox. Can anybody tell me from where/how to start and how to access items from sitecore workbox programmatically?

Comment: By cleanup, do you mean remove or approve that version?

Comment: we need to remove that version which is in draft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can gain access to the workbox items by using the WorkflowProvider. If you already know what is the workflow id, you can use the following to get the `IWorkflow`. This will allow you to access the item states.

```
var masterContents= Factory.GetDatabase("master").WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow("Your Workflow ID");
```

Then, from the `masterContents` you can retrieve all the items that match a state id. The state id is the item id of the `draft` item.

```
var masterContents= Factory.GetDatabase("master").WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow("Your Workflow ID");

var draftItems = masterContents.GetItems("your draft item id");

foreach (var draftItem in draftItems)
{
    //TODO - Remove the item version here
}
```

The `draftItems` returns a list of `DataUri` which allows you to access the specific item version, language etc.

```
foreach (var draftItem in draftItems)
{
    var item = Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(draftItem.ItemID, draftItem.Language, draftItem.Version);

    item.RecycleVersion();
}
```

Note that I have not yet tested the code but this is the basic idea how to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response!!! I will definitely try these steps out and update my comments here. But I have got the core idea of how & where to start.

Comment: I have approved, also I tried to upvote but somehow its not getting increased.